# Dell Monitor does not turn on

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell P2815Q. You can check the description on the link below:

http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Dell-28-Ultra-HD-4K-Monitor---P2815Q/productID.309552300

I have been using it for over a month now and suddenly what I have noticed is that when I disconnected my laptop and connected it back it just does not detect the monitor.

Now, monitor by itself also does not show vivid signs of life. I can click on the Power button which will blink exactly twice and then goes back to where it was.

I wish I could give more information but I am not seeing anything on the screen. I disconnected and connected back the power Cord and so did the Digital cord but it just does not light up

There there 4 buttons on the screen but pressing any of them also dont seem to help. Seems like the monitor is going to sleep mode as soon as I press the power button Just to blink when I press the power button back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your power supply is going bad. Try unplugging it from the wall and letting it sit for a while. If that doesn't work, it's probable that either the monitor itself or the power supply is bad. If you have a voltage meter I'd recommend making sure the output voltage is the same as the rated voltage.